# How to add a fadin effect on an element being removed from DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm tryna make to a custom modal, which works fine cause what I want to achieve is to click on X which remove the DOM element completely, and click on add to restore it back but I want now to add some fadin and fadeout effects when restoring and closing the modal, added to that the modal displays already when the page loads, I want it to only display when clicked. Can anyone help me please, I am a learner and newbie as well so, please

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toBeDeleted = $('.modal-backdrop');
  $('.blu-modal__close').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(toBeDeleted).detach().fadeOut(4000);
  });
  $('#buttonAdd').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($('body').find('.modal-backdrop').length == 0) {
      $('body').append(toBeDeleted).fadeOut(4000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 4000;
}

.blu-modal__container {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal__container {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__container {
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  padding-top: 16px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__container {
    border-radius: 16px;
  }
}

.blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__container {
  width: 480px;
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close i:before,
.b-page .blu-modal__close i:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close i:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close i:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__header {
    padding: 0 32px;
  }
}

.blu-modal__heading {
  font-family: "efframedium", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__image {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__image img {
  max-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__name-attr {
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__name-attr__attribute {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.blu-modal__body {
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal__body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 230px);
  }
}

.blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__body {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__body {
    padding: 0 32px;
  }
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__detail {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.attributes__section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.attributes--label-with-value {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.attributes--label {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: normal;
}

.attributes--value {
  overflow: scroll;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #0095da;
}

.b-flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 63.75em) {
  .product-variant__color__thumb__wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}

.product-variant__color__thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2px;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 63.75em) {
  <style>.product-variant__color__thumb {
    min-width: 60px;
    margin: 8px;
    display: -ms-inline-grid;
    display: inline-grid;
  }
}

.product-variant__image {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 63.75em) {
  .product-variant__image {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
}

.product-variant__image__selected {
  border-color: #41C3FF;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty__price__display {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #f37021;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty__price__display__list {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty__quantity {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.blu-modal__footer {
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__footer {
    padding: 16px 32px;
  }
}

.blu-modal__mask {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  
  <button type="button" class="" id="buttonAdd">Add</button>

  <div class="blu-modal modal-backdrop b-page">
    <div class="blu-modal__container">
      <button class="blu-modal__close">
            <i></i>
        </button>
      <div class="blu-modal__header">
        <div class="blu-modal__icon"></div>
        <h3 class="blu-modal__heading">
          <div class="modal__header">
            <div class="modal__header__image">
              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/full//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full05_mz4v26r0.jpg?output-format=webp" data-src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/full//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full05_mz4v26r0.jpg?output-format=webp"
                alt="iPhone 12 Mini 128GB Resmi" class="lazyImage" draggable="false" data-loaded="true">
            </div>
            <div class="modal__header__name-attr">
              <div class="modal__header__name-attr__name"> iPhone 12 Mini 128GB Resmi </div>
              <div class="modal__header__name-attr__attribute"> Red </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="blu-modal__body">
        <div class="modal__body">
          <div class="modal__body__detail">
            <div class="modal__body__detail__attribute">
              <div>
                <!---->
              </div>
              <div>
                <div id="attributes">
                  <div>
                    <div class="attributes__section">
                      <div class="attributes--label-with-value">
                        <div class="attributes--label">Warna</div>
                        <div class="attributes--label"> : Red </div>
                        <!---->
                      </div>
                      <div class="attributes--value">
                        <div>
                          <div class="product-variant__color__thumb__wrapper b-flex">
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full06_s5xmq8zt.jpg" alt="White" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full05_mz4v26r0.jpg" alt="Red" class="product-variant__image product-variant__image__selected">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full03_tdkcqg4k.jpg" alt="Green" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full02_ftornd3v.jpg" alt="Blue" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full01_ee17vwzj.jpg" alt="Black" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                          </div>
                          <div></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div 2f0="" class="modal__body__price-qty">
            <div class="modal__body__price-qty__price">
              <div>
                <strong class="modal__body__price-qty__price__display"> Rp11.548.000 </strong>
              </div>
              <div>
                <strong class="modal__body__price-qty__price__display__list"> Rp16.999.000 </strong>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal__body__price-qty__quantity">
              <button type="button" class="quantity-input-btn qtyminus btn-number input-box" field="quantity" data-id="1696">
                            <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
                        </button>
              <input type="number" min="1" class="quantity-input-value input-box" id="qty_1697" value="1">
              <button type="button" class="quantity-input-btn qtyplus btn-number input-box" field="quantity" data-id="1696">
                            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                        </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal__body__add-to-cart">
            <button type="button" class="blu-btn modal__body__add-to-cart__button b-full-width b-secondary">
                        <div class="blu-ripple">Tambah ke Bag </div>
                    </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blu-modal__footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blu-modal__mask"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You are fading out the whole body when the 'Add' button is clicked. And you are detaching the modal immediately after the 'x' button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? I just editing the jquery a little. Because the fadeOut() eventually sets display:none on the modal, the actual element is still on the page. So we can just reference it again when the add button is clicked.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var toBeDeleted = $('.modal-backdrop');
  $('.blu-modal__close').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(toBeDeleted).fadeOut(1000);
  });
  $('#buttonAdd').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.modal-backdrop').fadeIn(1000);
  });
});
```

```css
.modal-backdrop {
  z-index: 4000;
}

.blu-modal__container {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal__container {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}

.blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__container {
  max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
  padding-top: 16px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__container {
    border-radius: 16px;
  }
}

.blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__container {
  width: 480px;
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  right: 20px;
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close i:before,
.b-page .blu-modal__close i:after {
  content: '';
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close i:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.b-page .blu-modal__close i:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__header {
    padding: 0 32px;
  }
}

.blu-modal__heading {
  font-family: "efframedium", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__image {
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__image img {
  max-height: 100px;
  min-width: 100px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__name-attr {
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: auto 0;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__header__name-attr__attribute {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #BDBDBD;
}

.blu-modal__body {
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal__body {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 230px);
  }
}

.blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__body {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__body {
    padding: 0 32px;
  }
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__detail {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.attributes__section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.attributes--label-with-value {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

.attributes--label {
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  backdrop-filter: blur(4px);
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: top;
  line-height: normal;
}

.attributes--value {
  overflow: scroll;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #0095da;
}

.b-flex {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 63.75em) {
  .product-variant__color__thumb__wrapper {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}

.product-variant__color__thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2px;
  display: -ms-inline-flexbox;
  display: inline-flex;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 63.75em) {
  <style>.product-variant__color__thumb {
    min-width: 60px;
    margin: 8px;
    display: -ms-inline-grid;
    display: inline-grid;
  }
}

.product-variant__image {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #E0E0E0;
  border-radius: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 63.75em) {
  .product-variant__image {
    overflow: auto;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
  }
}

.product-variant__image__selected {
  border-color: #41C3FF;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty__price__display {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
  line-height: normal;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  color: #f37021;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty__price__display__list {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.48);
  font-size: 15px;
  text-decoration: line-through;
}

.modal-backdrop .modal__body__price-qty__quantity {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.blu-modal__footer {
  text-align: right;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 769px),
print {
  .blu-modal.b-page .blu-modal__footer {
    padding: 16px 32px;
  }
}

.blu-modal__mask {
  -webkit-transition: opacity .3s ease;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.64);
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <button type="button" class="" id="buttonAdd">Add</button>

  <div class="blu-modal modal-backdrop b-page">
    <div class="blu-modal__container">
      <button class="blu-modal__close">
            <i></i>
        </button>
      <div class="blu-modal__header">
        <div class="blu-modal__icon"></div>
        <h3 class="blu-modal__heading">
          <div class="modal__header">
            <div class="modal__header__image">
              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/full//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full05_mz4v26r0.jpg?output-format=webp" data-src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/full//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full05_mz4v26r0.jpg?output-format=webp"
                alt="iPhone 12 Mini 128GB Resmi" class="lazyImage" draggable="false" data-loaded="true">
            </div>
            <div class="modal__header__name-attr">
              <div class="modal__header__name-attr__name"> iPhone 12 Mini 128GB Resmi </div>
              <div class="modal__header__name-attr__attribute"> Red </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </h3>
      </div>
      <div class="blu-modal__body">
        <div class="modal__body">
          <div class="modal__body__detail">
            <div class="modal__body__detail__attribute">
              <div>
                <!---->
              </div>
              <div>
                <div id="attributes">
                  <div>
                    <div class="attributes__section">
                      <div class="attributes--label-with-value">
                        <div class="attributes--label">Warna</div>
                        <div class="attributes--label"> : Red </div>
                        <!---->
                      </div>
                      <div class="attributes--value">
                        <div>
                          <div class="product-variant__color__thumb__wrapper b-flex">
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full06_s5xmq8zt.jpg" alt="White" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full05_mz4v26r0.jpg" alt="Red" class="product-variant__image product-variant__image__selected">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full03_tdkcqg4k.jpg" alt="Green" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full02_ftornd3v.jpg" alt="Blue" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                            <figure class="product-variant__color__thumb">
                              <img src="https://www.static-src.com/wcsstore/Indraprastha/images/catalog/thumbnail//90/MTA-11741139/apple_iphone_12_mini_128gb_resmi_full01_ee17vwzj.jpg" alt="Black" class="product-variant__image">
                            </figure>
                          </div>
                          <div></div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
          </div>
          <div 2f0="" class="modal__body__price-qty">
            <div class="modal__body__price-qty__price">
              <div>
                <strong class="modal__body__price-qty__price__display"> Rp11.548.000 </strong>
              </div>
              <div>
                <strong class="modal__body__price-qty__price__display__list"> Rp16.999.000 </strong>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal__body__price-qty__quantity">
              <button type="button" class="quantity-input-btn qtyminus btn-number input-box" field="quantity" data-id="1696">
                            <span class="fa fa-minus"></span>
                        </button>
              <input type="number" min="1" class="quantity-input-value input-box" id="qty_1697" value="1">
              <button type="button" class="quantity-input-btn qtyplus btn-number input-box" field="quantity" data-id="1696">
                            <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
                        </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal__body__add-to-cart">
            <button type="button" class="blu-btn modal__body__add-to-cart__button b-full-width b-secondary">
                        <div class="blu-ripple">Tambah ke Bag </div>
                    </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="blu-modal__footer"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="blu-modal__mask"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but what I want to achieve is that I want the div element " modal-backdrop" containing the modal to be removed from the DOM, I don't want to hide it but completely remove it from DOM but with some fade-in and fadeout effects

Comment: Hmm. you can remove it from the dom after the fadeOut, but then how to reattach it? It won't be there anymore.